# Can I use both ES6 and ES5 in the same React codebase?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, gulp, browserify, babeljs

I have the following gulpfile.js:

```
var gulp = require('gulp');
var browserify = require('gulp-browserify');
var concat = require('gulp-concat');

gulp.task('browserify', function() {
    gulp.src('js/ScheduleMain.js')
      .pipe(browserify({transform:'reactify'}))
      .pipe(concat('ScheduleMain.js'))
      .pipe(gulp.dest('static/dist/js'));
    gulp.src('js/ConfidenceMain.js')
      .pipe(browserify({transform:'reactify'}))
      .pipe(concat('ConfidenceMain.js'))
      .pipe(gulp.dest('static/dist/js'));
});

gulp.task('default',['browserify']);

gulp.task('watch', function() {
    gulp.watch('src/**/*.*', ['default']);
});
```

As you can see I have two source files that need transforming. ScheduleMain.js is written in es5 and builds fine. I want to write my new application (ConfidenceMain.js) in es6 and possible transform it to es5 for build. I am a bit confused on how to do this (or rather if it is at all recommended).

**Bottom line:** Can I move forward with new react projects written in es6 syntax despite having es5 code previously for other projects in the same code base?

Comment: Your bottom line conflicts with your title question :/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, you can mix both ES6 and ES5 - ES6 is fully backwards compatible, so essentially you could think of your entire app as ES6, but only use the new syntax and functionality in new code.

You would need to add a transpilation step to your gulp pipeline to pass your code through babel and compile it down to ES5. Something like this:

```
var gulp = require('gulp');
var browserify = require('gulp-browserify');
var concat = require('gulp-concat');
var babel = require('gulp-babel');

gulp.task('browserify', function() {
    gulp.src('js/ScheduleMain.js')
      .pipe(browserify({transform:'reactify'}))
      .pipe(concat('ScheduleMain.js'))
      .pipe(gulp.dest('static/dist/js'));
    gulp.src('js/ConfidenceMain.js')
      .pipe(babel())
      .pipe(browserify({transform:'reactify'}))
      .pipe(concat('ConfidenceMain.js'))
      .pipe(gulp.dest('static/dist/js'));
});

gulp.task('default',['browserify']);

gulp.task('watch', function() {
    gulp.watch('src/**/*.*', ['default']);
});
```

Note that the code above wouldn't transpile ScheduleMain.js but you could easily do that if you wanted, to enable the use of ES6 features going forwards - just pipe it through `babel()` in the same way.

Note that babel will require some configuration - the [documentation](http://babeljs.io/docs/setup/#installation) will guide you through this. You'll want the [es2015](http://babeljs.io/docs/plugins/preset-es2015) and [react](http://babeljs.io/docs/plugins/preset-react) presets.

**Edit**: Given your use of browserify, a cleaner approach might be to use the [babelify](https://github.com/babel/babelify) transform instead:

```
gulp.src('js/ConfidenceMain.js')
  .pipe(browserify({transform:'babelify'}))
  .pipe(concat('ConfidenceMain.js'))
  .pipe(gulp.dest('static/dist/js'));
```

Comment: If Babel is used then reactify is not needed anymore... (if Babel is configured properly).

Comment: Good point, I missed that. Given the use of browserify, another option would be to use its babelify transform.

Comment: Not fully backwards compatible (but almost): http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/#sec-additions-and-changes-that-introduce-incompatibilities-with-prior-editions