# Is it OK to use "let" and "const" in pre-ES6 code?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, ecmascript-5

I'm (re)learning Javascript and it's been recommended to me to avoid mixing ES5 and ES6 type code.  But my IDE, Webstorm, keeps warning me that I should be using *let* and *const* in my code -- there are tons of yellow flags.  Of course I can just turn off those warnings, but should I always use *let* and *const* when appropriate, even if the rest of my code is, for the moment, "old school" javascript?  (As an aside, I'd welcome any links/advice on/to best practices transitioning to ES6, i.e. the best way to start introducing ES6 into your code).  Thanks!

Comment: What do you mean by "is it OK"? Are you transpiling?

Comment: I suppose -- and here I enter into the touchy-feely area that risks being down voted -- I'm looking for best practices.  I have a more senior programmer telling me "don't mix ES5/ES6 code" as meanwhile I'm getting warnings for not using _let_ and _const_  -- I suppose what I mean is should one _always_ use _let_ and _const_ these days, even if you're not using any other ES6 features?

Comment: Check this out it can help : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37329081/can-i-use-both-es6-and-es5-in-the-same-react-codebase

Comment: "don't mix ES5/ES6 code" makes no sense.  They're just language features; there is no reason to avoid one feature if you aren't using other ones.

Comment: Considering that 90% of the syntax/features of ES6 also exist in ES5, I don't see how this should even be possible. Maybe they mean "don't use ES6 features in an ES5 environment" or "don't use ES5 features that have been superseded by some ES6 features" (e.g. method definitions in object literals).

Comment: Thanks to all.  Indeed, the comment made to me was a bit puzzling, but I'm at the start of the learning curve so I took it in stride.

Answer (score 3):

**The basic answer to your question**: no, it is not ok to use `let` and `const` in true ES5. You need to use `var`. To add to that: if Webstorm is throwing those warnings but you are writing ES5 then your settings are wrong. Go to Settings > Languages & Frameworks > Javascript, and change your Javascript Language Version to ECMAScript 5.1. If you know you're writing ES5 then you should not have it set to be validating your code against the ES6 specification.

Here's some additional info:

Recently I've been working to hook up a transpiler ([Babel](https://babeljs.io/)) to convert all Javascript to ES5 compatible syntax in a production environment. If you want to use ES6 syntax, but still need to support non ES6 compliant browsers (IE9 - IE11 for example) then a transpliler like Babel is necessary. With that in mind I'd like to bring up some specific notes related to `let` and `const`.

In true ES6 using `let` to define a variable creates it within the scope of its block. That means that as soon as the block exits that named variable is discarded. Because of this, something like the following is possible:

```
const x = 'I am a constant';
if (1 == 1) {
  let x = 'Not here for long';
  console.log(x); // => 'Not here for long'
}
console.log(x); // => 'I am a constant';
```

When using `let` to create a block scoped instance of `x` that takes precedence over `const x` inside of this block (our if statement in this case). What Babel turns this into in order to make it compatible with ES5 browsers is actually quite smart:

```
var x = 'I am a constant';
if (1 == 1) {
  var _x = 'Not here for long';
  console.log(_x); // => 'Not here for long'
}
console.log(x); // => 'I am a constant';
```

As you can see here it actually creates a new var with a different name, `_x`, so it does not conflict with the original `x`.

**A final note**: If you are using new features like `Promise` and `Symbol` then a transpiler is not enough. You also need to be using a polyfill for those.

Comment: If the problem is that you have a mix of ES6 and ES5 code you can set the JS version on a per folder level (no per file support at this time).

https://blog.jetbrains.com/webstorm/2017/09/webstorm-2017-3-eap-173-2463/#multiple-js-versions